# No range function with step in azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a Set Variable activity which uses the logic:

```
@range(int(pipeline().parameters.start),int(pipeline().parameters.end))
```

It is wierd that I cant find any logic in documents where I can mention a step so that I can generate few numbers as shown below

```
1,3,5,7,9,...
```

Is there work around to it, other than introducin a new parameter that is equal to step and generate next number using logic `last = last+step.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this using the [Filter activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-filter-activity) and the `range` function.  Use the `range` function to generate all numbers and then the Filter condition with `mod` to get odd numbers, ie

| Property | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Items | @range(1,10) |
| Condition | @equals(mod(item(),2),1) |

A screenprint of the results:

[image]

The other way to do it would be just use a Lookup activity and query a numbers table.

I agree with you that it's a shame `range` does not have a `step` argument, and that generally the ADF expression language isn't a bit more fully featured.